# Geolocation Without SSL connection

Tags: html, geolocation

I am developing an application which uses geolocation coordinates.
I used the HTML5 geolocation feature to find out the location of the site visitor, but the issue is with Chrome which doesnt support GeoLocation on insecure origins.

```
  function showPosition(){
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            var positionInfo = "Your current position is (" + "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", " + "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude + ")";
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = positionInfo;
        });
    } else{
        alert("Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 geolocation.");
    }
}
```

Here is the code `getCurrentPosition`  is not working in as my site is not SSL connected .

**Warning by Chrome :** getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.

Is there any other way to get coordinates/LatLong values on chrome ? [on Insecure connection only]

**EDIT** : It is working in my machine using localhost:80 but not working in test url which is on http

Comment: Googled. But couldn't find good solution.

Comment: Obvious question: starting to use HTTPS is not an option…?

Comment: Https is an option. But just wanted to know if there is any alternative

Comment: you can use the Google Maps Geolocation API.

Comment: You could take a look at [gpsha.re](https://gpsha.re).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var apiGeolocationSuccess = function(position) {
    alert("API geolocation success!\n\nlat = " + position.coords.latitude + "\nlng = " + position.coords.longitude);
};

var tryAPIGeolocation = function() {
    jQuery.post( "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AIzaSyDCa1LUe1vOczX1hO_iGYgyo8p_jYuGOPU", function(success) {
        apiGeolocationSuccess({coords: {latitude: success.location.lat, longitude: success.location.lng}});
  })
  .fail(function(err) {
    alert("API Geolocation error! \n\n"+err);
  });
};

var browserGeolocationSuccess = function(position) {
    alert("Browser geolocation success!\n\nlat = " + position.coords.latitude + "\nlng = " + position.coords.longitude);
};

var browserGeolocationFail = function(error) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      alert("Browser geolocation error !\n\nTimeout.");
      break;
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      if(error.message.indexOf("Only secure origins are allowed") == 0) {
        tryAPIGeolocation();
      }
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      alert("Browser geolocation error !\n\nPosition unavailable.");
      break;
  }
};

var tryGeolocation = function() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        browserGeolocationSuccess,
      browserGeolocationFail,
      {maximumAge: 50000, timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
  }
};

tryGeolocation();
```

Comment: This solution doesn't return accurate coordinates

Comment: There is also a daily/monthly/etc usage quota on this Google API.

Comment: For pricing information visit https://mapsplatformtransition.withgoogle.com/calculator

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does all this code solve the given problem?

Comment: Also, don't assume everyone uses jQuery. What a mess.

Answer (score 38):

Really simple: open Chrome, open this address and enter the domains you wish to enable for

```
chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure
```

[image]

This way it's permanent and you don't need to open the chrome browser each time with

```
google-chrome --args --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://whatever.test"
```

as answered above.

Comment: Best way to do it! Thanks!

Comment: That should be definitely the answer ;)

Answer (score 12):

Chrome now prevents untrusted sites from using html5 geolocation. Trusted sites include `localhost`or any https certified domain. In my case neither of these were possible so instead i opened chrome from the command line with this argument: `open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app' --args --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure="http://yoursite.test"` Which added my particular domain as a trusted site.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my non SSL solution for Safari in 2017/05

```
var apiGeolocationSuccess = function(position) {
    alert("API geolocation success!\n\nlat = " + position.coords.latitude + "\nlng = " + position.coords.longitude);
};

var tryAPIGeolocation = function() {
    jQuery.post( "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AIzaSyDCa1LUe1vOczX1hO_iGYgyo8p_jYuGOPU", function(success) {
        apiGeolocationSuccess({coords: {latitude: success.location.lat, longitude: success.location.lng}});
    })
        .fail(function(err) {
            alert("API Geolocation error! \n\n"+err);
        });
};

var browserGeolocationSuccess = function(position) {
    alert("Browser geolocation success!\n\nlat = " + position.coords.latitude + "\nlng = " + position.coords.longitude);
};

var browserGeolocationFail = function(error) {
    switch (error.code) {
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            alert("Browser geolocation error !\n\nTimeout.");
            break;
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            if(error.message.indexOf("Only secure origins are allowed") == 0) {
                tryAPIGeolocation();
            }
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            // dirty hack for safari
            if(error.message.indexOf("Origin does not have permission to use Geolocation service") == 0) {
                tryAPIGeolocation();
            } else {
                alert("Browser geolocation error !\n\nPosition unavailable.");
            }
            break;
    }
};

var tryGeolocation = function() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            browserGeolocationSuccess,
            browserGeolocationFail,
            {maximumAge: 50000, timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
    }
};

tryGeolocation();
```

The new part is this one in "case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE":

```
case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
// dirty hack for safari
if(error.message.indexOf("Origin does not have permission to use Geolocation service") == 0) {
    tryAPIGeolocation();
} else {
    alert("Browser geolocation error !\n\nPosition unavailable.");
}
break;
```