# Fetch latitude and longitude on user's current location

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssl, https, geolocation

I want to fetch user's Lattitude and Longitude value on user's current location. My asp.net web application runs on **HTTP** protocol and as per the Google's developer guide, the application must be running on HTTPS protocol to use HTML5 GeoLocation Service. Somehow I found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/39367531/7057220 and I tried this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            var apiGeolocationSuccess = function (position) {
                alert("API geolocation success!\n\nlat = " + position.coords.latitude + "\nlng = " + position.coords.longitude);
            };
            var tryAPIGeolocation = function () {
                debugger;
                jQuery.post("https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=MyAPIKey", function (success) {
                    apiGeolocationSuccess({ coords: { latitude: success.location.lat, longitude: success.location.lng } });
                })
              .fail(function (err) {
                  alert("API Geolocation error! \n\n" + err);
              });
            };

            var browserGeolocationSuccess = function (position) {
                debugger;
                alert("Browser geolocation success!\n\nlat = " + position.coords.latitude + "\nlng = " + position.coords.longitude);
            };

            var browserGeolocationFail = function (error) {
                switch (error.code) {
                    case error.TIMEOUT:
                        alert("Browser geolocation error !\n\nTimeout.");
                        break;
                    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                        if (error.message.indexOf("Only secure origins are allowed") == 0) {
                            tryAPIGeolocation();
                        }
                        break;
                    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                        alert("Browser geolocation error !\n\nPosition unavailable.");
                        break;
                }
            };
            var tryGeolocation = function () {
                debugger;
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                        browserGeolocationSuccess,
                      browserGeolocationFail,
                      { maximumAge: 50000, timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
                }
            };
            tryGeolocation();
        });
    </script>
```

The problem is whenever I run this code it always gives me incorrect Latitude and Longitude values. I want to know that what I'm doing wrong in it. So, how can I use Geolocation without SSL Connection

Comment: What lat:lon do you expect and what incorrect value do you get?

Comment: `it always gives me incorrect Latitude and Longitude values` - which part does? `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`? or is it `jQuery.post("https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=MyAPIKey`

Comment: expected values(as per my current location): 28.4523609,77.067686, actual result 28.6862738, 77.2217831 which is wrong

Answer (score 1):

you can use the simple Javascript code which I found on W3schools

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
 alert('Latitude: '+position.coords.latitude +'Longitude: '+ position.coords.longitude);
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your response but I've already tried this before and more important this example only works on HTTPS Protocol. My application runs over HTTP Protocol.

Comment: Geolocation API Removed from Unsecured Origins in Chrome 50  Google have stop API Support for unsecured i.e. http website explore below article                                       https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");


 
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
 var a = position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude;

 alert(a);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```