# Geolocation result display NaN

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the geolocation of a user visiting my website. I love this simple 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp' code when I use the try it yourself it displayed the lat and long. I tried it on my website, is ok. but another trying given me NaN. from both the w3school site and my site. please, how can I solve the problem?

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct so I'm only guessing that maybe you're trying your code on a server/domain without https. This is now mandatory in several mainstream browsers, so you can only use the geolocation api if you are under https.

You can read more about it here : [Geolocation Without SSL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366758/geolocation-without-ssl-connection)

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. I really understand this and my site is HTTPS. This even happened when I used 'try it youself' at 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp'. Any further assistance

Comment: I would advise you to look closely to the developer tools console of your browser because usually that's where more detailed information about errors gets logged.
That's all I can say, since I'm unable to replicate your issue.

Comment: Thanks very much. I figured out that this has to do with desktop browser only. And since i only need it on mobile app and its working fine on mobile browser i just ignored it. Thanks again