# Google Chrome "Allow Location" option DISABLED when ASP NET MVC 6.0 Aplication is deployed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, geolocation

[My script in view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bjb9.png)

When deployed on localhost:5001 the browser will ask for permission to access location and everything is ok!

But when I Deploy it on server, i change launchSettings to http://my.server.ip:port/
Then It will not access location and the option both in Chrome or Edge to allow acess to user location appears DISABLED.
Edit : Im host on a DDNS.NET, standalone in a windows server.

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bjb9.png)

[chrome01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWltR.png)

[chrome disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxO14.png)

Comment: https://mobiforge.com/news-comment/no-https-then-bye-bye-geolocation-in-chrome-50

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Geolocation Without SSL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366758/geolocation-without-ssl-connection)

Comment: More or less yes. Adding my domain as unsafety treat insecure origin on chrome will make it work. The Problem is that I will have to run this command on all my clients cellphones.

Comment: Add Https to your website